# Outgoing mails to spam directory

Tags: email, phpmailer, vps, spam, postfix-mta

I've VPS.
I installed postfix and what is necessary for mail server.
(I've used this as a guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-postfix-on-centos-6 )

then, I configured my DNS as recomended. (this is my configure http://t1308.hizliresim.com/1d/7/r834r.png)

But there's still problem that: my mails are going to the spam directory? why? what should I do?

I've checked banlists and there's no problem about black lists.

Any idea? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To see if your mail server has a glaring problem that would cause other mail servers to think it's a spammer, try sending a message from your mail server to `check-auth@verifier.port25.com`. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such whether or not your mail server's DNS is setup correctly, whether your mail server's IP is on any black lists, if you have a problem with your SPF records, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the setup side, but several other factors could cause it to hit spam folders. Try removing one possible cause at a time until the email works.

1. replace all the content with pure text (no $, !'s or large numbers)
2. send from a different email address
3. send to a different email address on a different domain

If any of those fix your problem, you should have it narrowed down to the cause, which will help the rest of us to give more targeted answers. If those things don't make a difference, then it is most likely in your setup.